# Editing a theme

Tags: plugins, theme-development, themes

I am making a wordpress site which is already online.
URL: http://eventosis.com
I want to add two buttons in the header of the site. How do I go about it? I have very little programming experience.The theme I used is Customizr.

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck. Please file an [edit] with your code and explain/point out where your code is failing you. Thank you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have no coding experience the easiest would be to add a text widget in the header section and use an image of the button and make it link to where you want it to go. Just upload the image to your media and then check the URL of the image in media.

Something like this:

```
<a href="landingpageURL">
  <img src="buton.jpg" alt="Button alt text" style="width:42px;height:42px;border:0;">
</a>
```